# App crashes when i use an extended custom view

Tags: android

why my app crashes when I use extended view

Here is my extended view

```
public class CustomView extends View
{
    CustomView(Context c)
    {
        super(c);
        init(null);
    }

    CustomView(Context c, AttributeSet attr)
    {
        super(c, attr);
        init(attr);
    }

    public void init(AttributeSet attr)
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

}
```

This is the layout file

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

         <com.mycompany. LearnCanvas.CustomView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="200dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run my app, it crashes.

Comment: Please post crash log first.

Comment: You are missing a constructor which is used by xml, Add this `public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        
    }`

Comment: Thnx, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a constructor which is used by xml. Add this constructor

```
public CustomView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```